# Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidSchedulers ' on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() using implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0'

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I am trying to follow a few code examples to pull a single record from the database to display, because it seems somewhat complicated to do so with LiveData. However, I am getting an error in the IDE.

Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidSchedulers'

on the line:

```
AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
```

in this call:

```
        viewModel.getScenario(scenarioId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<Scenario>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Scenario scenario) {

                    }
                });
```

My grade has this:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have missing `implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'` in your `gradle`. `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` is part of `rxandroid` not a   `rxjava2`

Comment: That helped. Thank you. Now I am getting: Class 'Anonymous class derived from DisposableSingleObserver' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onError(Throwable)' in 'SingleObserver'